# How to add new line in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code to create dynamic labels in c#. I need to add a newline after every labels.

```
 MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
 for (int i = 0;dr.Read(); i++)
 {
     Label NewLabel = new Label();
     NewLabel.ID = dr.GetString(0);
     NewLabel.Text = dr.GetString(1);
     this.pnlInfo.Controls.Add(NewLabel);

 }
```

How to add?

Comment: Tagged as `asp.net` due to `ID` property not present in `winforms` or `wpf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an HTML line break to your panel after you add the label, like so:

```
this.pnlInfo.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
```

This will actually add a line break after your label on the page.

Answer (score 5):

`NewLabel.Text = dr.GetString(1) + Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: You need to use the HTML line break.

Comment: @shree.pat18: What makes you think that this is a web app?

Comment: @leppie My bad. Assumed it because web app questions are more common in my experience than those for WinForms.

Comment: but still is comes in single line

Comment: @shree.pat18: For all we know it might be :) Looking at the code that `ID` property looks 'webby'. Edit: Actually it is! Good spot ;p

Comment: If it is HTML then style="margin-bottom:1em" should do :)

Answer (score 2):

You can Use `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 2):

```
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
for (int i = 0; dr.Read(); i++)
{
    Label NewLabel = new Label();
    NewLabel.ID = dr.GetString(0);
    NewLabel.Text = dr.GetString(1);
    this.pnlInfo.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
    this.pnlInfo.Controls.Add(new Literal() { Text = System.Environment.NewLine }); //here
}
```